# GitHub PR's merge commit replays changes that are already in main

Tags: git, github

I just had the following situation come up with a pull request:

- I had a new repository that only had `main`, which had a lot of my commits
- My coworker branched off of it to `other_branch`, and started doing work.
- I think I made some more commits to `main` after they created their branch. Let's call these commits `A, B, C`
- They started a pull request. Looking at the PR in GitHub it seemed fine and only contained "good" changes. Let's call these commits from the branch `D, E, F`
- I approved the PR and pulled down the updates to `main`.
- When I look at GitHub's commit list for `main` I see all my commits, followed by all their commits, followed by `Merge pull request #4` which is from when I approved it. So I see `A, B, C, D, E, F, Merge pull request #4`

But on my laptop when I run:

```
git diff [commit hash of my coworker's last commit from their branch which is now present in main]..[commit hash of "Merge pull request #4", i.e. from when I approved the PR]
```

what I *expect* to see is the consolidated result of all of their commits `D, E, F`, i.e. the same thing I saw in GitHub when I was reviewing the PR. Because my `git diff` command is just asking "what changes are in this merge commit?"

What I *actually* see is the consolidated result of my own recent commits, i.e. `A, B, C`, and my coworker's commits aren't even in the diff. The `git diff` result makes it look like those changes weren't already in `main`, even though they actually were (which I have verified by browsing the state of the repo prior to the merge commit).

I'm trying to figure out what I'm misunderstanding and also confirm that the repo isn't somehow corrupted.

Comment: Did you pull main?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah, I ran just `git pull`. I have the full history locally on my laptop including the merge commit and commits that were merged from the branch, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to run `git dt`. It's just that it looks super strange.

Comment: A merge commit is different from _any other commit_. It isn't the same as the last commit before it in either branch that contributes to the merge.

Comment: Also, by the way, you should not be making _any_ commits directly on `main`. All work should now be done through feature branches and pull requests.

Comment: @matt yeah, we are going to start doing that. This was a new repo to which I've only made a handful of commits. We are moving to feature branches now that it is getting serious, which is how we came across this behavior.

Comment: Also what is `git dt`?

Comment: @matt Oh, my mistake. It is same as `git diff`. I forgot I had it aliased. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is merely (as I think you already implied) that you don't understand what merging is, plus you may have false expectations about how information about the repository is displayed in various contexts. Nothing is actually wrong. Let's explore further!

First, let's establish a few fundamental truths. A "branch" in Git is merely a name attached to a single commit. Other commits are available thru a step by step backward traversal, because every commit (except the very first commit you ever made) has a *parent* to which it points. We may say that those other commits are *reachable* from a branch commit thru this traversal.

Now then. You are describing this:

```
X -- Y -- Z -- A -- B -- C (main)
           \
             ---- D -- E -- F (otherbranch)
```

If `otherbranch` is now passed up to GitHub as a PR branch (I say "GitHub" because PRs are not at all a Git feature, in fact they are a complete perversion of Git but let's not go into that), it will be displayed as consisting of D, E, and F, because those are the commits *reachable from `otherbranch` but not from `main`.* That result is calculated by a *double-dot log*, like this:

```
git log main..otherbranch
```

Okay, now let's say you are on `main` and you merge `otherbranch` into it. I don't care how you do that; you could pass thru the PR process of approval and merge, or else you could say

```
git switch main
git merge otherbranch
```

The important thing is that we are supposing that if you did a PR approval and merge, you asked for a *true merge*, that is, you said Merge as your merge option. Two other options, Squash and Merge, and Rebase and Merge, are very different and are not to be used lightly.

Very well, then you would now have this:

```
X -- Y -- Z -- A -- B -- C -- M (main)
           \                 /
             ---- D -- E -- F (otherbranch)
```

... where M is a newly created commit, formed out of whole cloth by Git, and with the remarkable property that it has *two parents*. In other words, it is that very special animal we call a *merge commit.*

Now, what commits are reachable from `main` at this point? In the immortal words of Sarah Palin, "all of them!" M is reachable because it *is* `main`, and all the others are reachable because M can reach both C and F and from either of those you can trace your way all the way back to X.

When you ask GitHub to display that information (all commits), it doesn't do a very good job, because it doesn't draw a graph. A better option would be to `git fetch` and then use `git log main` with the "god" options `--graph --oneline --decorate` so that you see the history in a nice way.

Now let's talk about your "on my laptop" experience. First of all, absolutely nothing is going to work right until you have said `git fetch`. Once you do that, you say you said what amounts to

```
git diff F..M
```

which is actually identical to

```
git diff F M
```

That is a very odd thing to ask for, but let's go with it. Well, what is M? It consists of contributions made from-Z-to-C, on the one hand, and from-Z-to-F, on the other hand (because that is what a merge commit is: it is formed by *merge logic*, which I have explained [elsewhere](https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/) and won't go into right now). But F already expresses what happened on the from-Z-to-F side, so since you are asking for the *difference* between M and F, that material is *not* a difference — it is the *same*. So it does *not* appear in the diff, because that is what "difference" means.

What *does* appear in the difference is the stuff that F does *not* express or even know about, namely, your contributions over on the from-Z-to-C side of the ledger: in other words, exactly what you say you *did* see — "the consolidated result of my own recent commits". To put it another way: the merge commit effectively adds to F (which is, or was, `otherbranch`) everything that happened since the point where `otherbranch` diverged from `main` — and that is exactly what the diff shows you.

So don't worry, be happy. Either you don't understand what a merge commit is or you don't understand what your `diff` command does, but either way, what you see is exactly what is expected and you should just relax.

---

<sub>Note: Your title is "GitHub PR's merge commit replays changes that are already in main". Yes! That is exactly what a merge commit *is*. It replays the changes that took place on `main` but not on `otherbranch`, and it also replays the changes that took place on `otherbranch` but not on `main`. Isn't that what you would intuitively want merging to mean? Your diff simply eliminated half of those changes from the report of what the merge did.</sub>

---

<sub>Final note: If your goal was to find out how each side contributed to the merge, you probably wanted a *triple-dot* diff. As I tell you in the article I already linked to: "If you are on `master` and you are about to merge `otherbranch` into it, say `git diff otherbranch...` and `git diff ...otherbranch` to see the `master` diff and the `otherbranch` diff, respectively." Those are the two "sets of changes" that Git will attempt to enact *simultaneously* by the creation of the merge commit.</sub>

<sub>Or, if what you wanted to know is what the overall progress of things has been *after* (and thanks to) the merge, then you should have asked for `diff Z main`, where Z (as shown in my diagram) is the point at which the two branches diverged, aka the merge base.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. I will need to review this in more detail a bit later as I've been pulled into a different project, but it is good to hear that things are OK :).